# How to use mw.site.siteName in Module:Asbox

Tags: mediawiki

Exporting Template:Stub from Wikipedia for use on non-WMF wiki, it transcludes Scribunto Module:Asbox which has on line 233:

> ' is a [[Wikipedia:stub|stub]]. You can help Wikipedia by [',

Substituting *Wikipedia* with magic word {{SITENAME}} doesn't work here. How to replace *Wikipedia* for the comparable Lua function *mw.site.siteName*, so that pages transcluding the stub template shows the local wiki name instead?

Comment: FWIW `{{SITENAME}}` is generally the wrong thing to do (no guarantees that is the name of the namespace); you'd want to replace it with `Project`, or `{{ns:Project}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [mw.site.namespaces](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto/Lua_reference_manual#mw.site.namespaces):

```
' is a [[' .. mw.site.namespaces.Project.name .. ':stub|stub]]. You can help ' .. mw.site.siteName .. ' by ['
```